# Using int Addition may got the wrong answer on some android phone

Tags: android

I get a strange problem on some android phones, when I run the code below.

```
public void test(){
    int num = 1;
    for(int i=0;i<14;i++){
        num = num+100000;
    }
    System.out.println("num  "+num);
}
```

I expect the answer "1400001", but I get the wrong answer "200385" on the phone like MotoX 2ndGen, Xiaomi3, Xiaomi note etc.

The strangest thing is that I can get the right answer when I want to debug it, or complicate the code like

```
public void test(){
        int num = 1;
        for(int i=0;i<14;i++){
            num = num+100000;
            System.out.println("num  "+num);
        }
    }
```

or

```
public void test(){
        int num1 = 1;
        for(int i=0;i<14;i++){
            num1 = num1+100000;
        }
        System.out.println("num1  "+num1);
        int num2 = 1;
        for(int i=0;i<14;i++){
            num2 = num2+100000;
        }
        System.out.println("num2  "+num2);
    }
```

or turn `int` to `long`, or make "100000" to 100, it can get the right answer usually. So what is the reason behind this phenomenon? An integer overflow maybe?
supplement:
I test int size on the wrong phones is 32 , and the max value is 2147483647,as others.And I find that one of results would overflow on "131072" ，changing to binary is 2^17.And all of the wrong result occur on fourfold times in "for" code,like the fourth , the eighth.so why?

Comment: use long datatype instead of int and try for num variable

Comment: using long datatype is correct . I want to know the reason about integer.

Comment: check size of int in bytes

Comment: size is 32 and max value is 2147483647;

Comment: I test int size on the wrong phones is 32 , and the max value is 2147483647,as others.And I find that one of results would overflow on "131072" ，changing to binary is 2^17.And all of the wrong result occur on fourfold times in "for" code,like the fourth , the eighth.so why?

Answer (score 0):

Try to print out [Integer.MAX_VALUE](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) and [Integer.SIZE](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html#SIZE). This should always be 2147483647 (max) and 32 (size in bits).

Do you print inside the for loop or outside?? If inside, try to use System.out.flush() after the for-loop.

Comment: I test int size on the wrong phones is 32 , and the max value is 2147483647,as others.And I find that one of results would overflow on "131072" ，changing to binary is 2^17.And all of the wrong result occur on fourfold times in "for" code,like the fourth , the eighth etc.so why?